# Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSMutableDictionary : Any]' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: swift

Below code has some error that I couldn't understand:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSMutableDictionary : Any]' with an index of type 'String'

The related code:

```
class func getCountryID(_ countryName: String?) -> String? {
    let countryarray = DCUserDetails.getSavedData()![keyCountryDetail] as? [Any]

    for countryDict: [AnyHashable : Any]? in countryarray as? [[AnyHashable : Any]?] ?? [] {
        if (countryDict?["CountryName"] == countryName) {
            return "\(Int(countryDict?["CountryId"] ?? 0))"
        }
    }

    return "0"
}
```

Comment: Too many `Any` and too many question marks. What is the return type of `getSavedData()` (the Swift type, not `NSDictionary`)? This is Swift, please be more careful with the types. For example why is the parameter and the return value of the function optional although no optional is returned?

Comment: @vadian return type of getSavedData() is NSMutableDictionary

Comment: could you do a `print(DCUserDetails.getSavedData())` and post that with your answer? and also  value of `keyCountryDetail `